# Need to select from SQL where in a list

Tags: sql

I have an SQL table and I need to select all the records where username (MM_Session) is in another users following list (Users SQL table, following column), which would look like this

username1 username2  username3  username4

So far, my SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE Users.Following_By LIKE '" . $_SESSION['MM_Username'] . "'
```

Except that doesn't seem to return any values even though the user's username is in the other users following list.

Should I be using 'IN' instead of 'LIKE'?

Does anyone have any other ideas why this isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And what programming language is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator works just the same as `=` if you don't use wildcard characters in your query string. Place them before and behind the word to match any occurrence of the word:

```
SELECT *
 FROM Users
 WHERE Users.Following_By LIKE '%" . $_SESSION['MM_Username'] . "%'
```

Though you might get more users than you expected because it matches for example `foobar` if `MM_USERname` contains only `foo`. You could use explicit delimiters to prevent this. Or, even better, use a separate table for the list entries and use a foreign key to join it to the `Users` table.

Comment: Thank you. I don't really know why I didn't think of this before. It's such an obvious answer.

Comment: Yes, I did try earlier but it said I had to wait 10 minutes. It's done now.